# How to move all windows to another display in Windows 10 quickly?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Windows 10 mostly with two displays:

1. The integrated monitor of my laptop.
2. An external HDMI monitor, this is what I mostly use.

Sometimes (particularly after the plug in / out of the external HDMI) most windows move to (1).

Does some quick way exist, most ideally a keyboard shortcut, to move all Windows from (1) to (2)?

Also some script-based solution would be okay, if such a shortcut does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have such a shortcut, so third-party software
is required.

This requires some testing, but
[MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
could be useful.
My idea is based on the fact that when a monitor is
turned off, all its windows are moved to another monitor.

Here is how to test the idea:

- Start MultiMonitorTool on one monitor
- Use its user interface to turn of the other monitor
- See if the windows on the first monitor have moved to the
  second one.

If the windows did move then my idea is working, and you could
use a script similar to the following to move back the windows:

```
\path\MultiMonitorTool /disable 1
timeout /t 5 >nul
\path\MultiMonitorTool /enable 1
```

Comment: Thanks, very good! Note: `MultiMonitorTool /disable 1` is what most people wants. `turnoff` turns off the monitor without notifying the OS/apps. Also `/turnoff 1` did not work by me, I could only turn off the secondary monitor. But I could disable any of them.

Comment: Additional note: next thing will be to bind this command to a shortcut. I am googling for that. :-)

Comment: I changed my answer to disable/enable.